# Is this right sentence without 'and'? (ran to her room pounced on him)

Tags: conjunctions, syntax

I think that this sentence needs 'and' after the word 'room'.
Am I wrong?
See this picture below.
I think that 'pounced'is the past form of the verb 'pounce' in this sentence.
Could you Please tell me why there is no 'and' in this sentence.
And can I use 'comma' here instead of 'and'?

[image]

Comment: Several things about this sentence indicate that it was not written by a native English speaker. Besides the missing "and", I don't expect "got a diabetic seizure" ('had' or 'suffered' or 'went into' are all more likely); and "pounce" is an odd choice of word, since that means "jump on when hunting". I would expect 'jump'

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's effectively ***proofreading*** (of some unidentified non-native speaker's poor quality text).

Comment: You should also write out the sentence rather than simply attach an image of it. [This Meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/screenshots-in-questions-what-should-we-do-to-discourage-such-behavior/) gives some of the reasons. (Yes, I'm aware that the Meta post followed this question by a few years.)

Comment: Yes, it's badly translated English. Some or all of the "and" can ber replaced by commas as it's a list of consecutive actions. But it is still ambiguous as to who called for medical assistance, the son or the cat!

Comment: I believe the intent of the "proofreading" close reason was to stop people using this site as a way to delegate their homework. Putting questions about third party writing into the proofreading category effectively means anybody who provides a sentence and asks "what's going on here? Can you explain why this doesn't meet my expectations of normal English" falls foul of the peoofreading test. That seems counterproductive to the aims of this site to me.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment. For a learner, other people's writing has an apparent authority because they can't tell the difference between a mistake and their own ignorance of the language. It's highly useful to be able to ask "is this good English or a mistake" _of somebody else's English_ so they can decide whether to learn from the example or ignore it. It can only be done with the help of more qualified peers. Proof reading _your own_ English, by contrast, is a matter of saying "I know this text probably has mistakes, but I can't be bothered working out what they are myself".

Answer (score 2):

No, there should be an "and" in the sentence because it is a *compound* action - the cat did A **and** then the cat did B.  You could omit the comma if you were making a *list* of actions, at least until before the last action.  Examples of these kind of lists:

> The cat ran into the room, pounced on the son, and ran out.
>
> We drove to the campsite, set up the tent, and lit a fire.

Here there are only two connected actions so they should be joined in some way, as in these examples:

> The cat caught the bird in mid-flight and brought it inside to show off to her owners.
>
> The cat knocked the glass off of the shelf, and then, for no reason, knocked another off.
>
> The cat sharpened her claws on the new sofa and then threw up on the new rug.

(Side note:  As a cat owner, I don't believe this story about the cat saving her owner.  My examples are much more plausible.)

Comment: I could omit the comma?  misspell of 'and'?